# Lexical Analysis for import and method calls in java

Tags: java, tokenize, conceptual, lexical

How are `import` statements and method calls tokenized in java's lexical analysis. For example:

`import java.util.Scanner`

is this seen as `import`, `java`, `util`, `Scanner`(4 tokens) or `import`, `java.util.Scanner`(2 tokens)

In the same line of thought, in:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = input.nextInt();
```

is `input.nextInt()` seen as `input`, `nextInt()` (2 tokens) or `input.nextInt()`  (1 token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lexical analysis is described in [Chapter 3 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.5).

This means in your first example, it would be tokenized as

```
keyword: import 
whitespace 
identifier: java 
seperator: . 
identifier: util 
seperator: .
identifier: Scanner
seperator: ;
```

So neither 2 nor 4, but 8 tokens (since whitespace and seperators are tokens according to the JLS).

Similary, `input.nextInt();` is 6 tokens, since both `(` and `)` are one token each (See [JLS § 3.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.11)).

Comment: Better late then never

Answer (score -2):

I believe import would be 1 lexical ananlysis. Apache Antlr is the tool that defines the grammar. Java is the same too.

I would recommend using Apache Antlr by importing the Java grammar. This would give the correct solution.